# Simple html dom doesn't work properly

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have a problem with simple html dom on php 5.5.8. I have code like that:

```
//Getting page content    
$t=$this->curl->getResponse();
//Show page content
echo $t;
//Parse with simple html dom and show result
$dm=str_get_html($t);
echo $dm->save();
```

After I run the code, I see that

```
echo $t;
```

returns something like that:

```
<output omitted>    
<span style="display:block;">ORGANIZATION CODE:123456789ABCD</span></div>
            </div><br><div id="pageTitle">
              <h1>Select your flights</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="yellowheader"></div>
            <div id="navDiv">
              <ol id="tripmeter">
                <ul><span class="tripmeterNotSelected"><a href="AS.aspx" onclick="S.DisplayLoadingBar();">Search Flight</a></span></ul>
                <ul id="tripmeterLink"><span id="tripmeterSelected">Select Flight</span><div id="tripmeterTail"></div>
                </ul>
                <ul><span class="tripmeterNotSelected">Guest Details</span></ul>
                <ul><span class="tripmeterNotSelected">Add-Ons</span></ul>
                <ul><span class="tripmeterNotSelected">Payment</span></ul>
                <ul><span class="tripmeterNotSelected">Itinerary Receipt</span></ul>
              </ol>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="selectMainBody" class="main">
            <div id="errorDiv"></div><input type="hidden" name="xxxxxxxxxxx" id="xxxxxxxx"><div id="tourBasingDialog" style="display:block;"><br><center>
<output omitted>
```

While

```
echo $dm->save();
```

returns

```
<output omitted>
        <span style="display:block;">ORGANIZATION CODE:123456789ABCD</span>
        </div>          </div><br></div> 
               <div id="selectMainBody" class="main">          <div id="errorDiv"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="xxxxxxxx" id="xxxxxxx">
    <div id="tourBasingDialog" style="display:block;"><br>
    EOF
```

As you can see, after str_get_html() as save() page content changed and cutted. Why it happened?

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out basically. That html was a mess to start with.

Answer (score 0):

you're missing something at some point, but `Simple HTML Dom Parser` working fine.

I copied your html into file, loaded that file using `file_get_contents('content.htm');` and printed that stuff.

and hence, after calling the `$html->save();` displayed and got the same output.

```
require_once 'dom.php';

$html = file_get_contents('content.htm');
echo "<h2>Complete File</h2>";
echo $html ;
$html = str_get_html($html);
echo "<hr />";
echo "<h2>After calling save()</h2>";
echo $html->save("dump.html");    //save stuff to dump.html file
```

and that gave me this output

[image]

output of `dump.html`

[image]